# Where can I find specific menu files in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website using the "Jupiter" Theme (http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter-demo/). I have created 2 custom navigation menus that are displayed in the header. One is displayed when the user is not logged in, the other is displayed when the user us logged in.

I need to make a few modifications to the code of the navigation menu but I can't seem to find the file that contains the code for the custom menus.

I have checked several of the files in "Appearance" > "Editor" - actions/header.php, header.php, general.php. In actions/header.php I found the code that loads the custom menu but it doesn't tell me where the menu itself lives.

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && !empty($mk_options['loggedin_menu'])) {
    $menu_location = $mk_options['loggedin_menu'];  
} else {
    $menu_location = 'primary-menu';    
}
```

Anyone here able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are the modifications you need to do?

Comment: I need to add some functionality to one of the menu items that I can't add by using the built in theme editor (by that I don't mean the files under Appearance > Editor but the UI that lets you create and to a limited degree modify your menus).

Comment: Would taking a look at the menu walker help you? http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker